# How to print custom attribute on Product listing page?

Tags: layout

my catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Product\CustomAttribute" name="custom.attribute" template="YourVendor_YourModule::product/custom_attribute.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

my custom_attribte.phtml

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$attrData = $product->getData('feature');
$blockTitle = $this->getData('title');
if ($attrData !== "") : ?>
    <div class="product-full-width-section">
        <h2 class="product-section-title"><?= $blockTitle; ?></h2>
        <?php echo $attrData; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Go to `Stores -> Attributes -> Product`, search for your attribute code `feature` and check in the storefront properties if you have enabled "Used in Product Listing"

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below point.

To create the attributes from the admin panel, the admin will navigate to **Stores > Attributes > Products.**

Tapping the **Product** menu option brings up another page to **add** product attributes. Here, click the “**Add New Attribute**” button to add a new attribute. and then save the attribute.

After that, to assign this attribute to an attribute set navigate to **Stores > Attributes > Attribute Sets.** and save.

Then after you need to create a helper in your module.

**app/code/Vendor/Catalog/Helper/classname.php**

```
 <?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Vendor\Catalog\Helper;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
    
    
    class ClassName extends AbstractHelper
    {
        protected $_registry;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
            Context $context
        ) {
            $this->_registry = $registry;
            $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
    
        public function getAttributes(){
    
           return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
        }
        public function getAttributeFilter($content){
            
           return $this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($content);
        }
    
       
    }
```

and you can get attributes in your Phtml file using the below code.

```
<?php 
    $eavHelper = $this->helper(vendor\Catalog\Helper\ClassName::class);
    $product = $eavHelper->getAttributes();
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please following the below step

Stores -> Attributes -> Product

and check your attribute code feature and check in the storefront properties if you have enabled "Used in Product Listing"

Hope it is help for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a custom product attribute value on the category page then kindly update your code in the `catalog_category_view.xml` layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.attribute" template="YourVendor_YourModule::product/custom_attribute.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

Now you can get the product attribute values in the `custom_attribute.phtml` file.

Kindly accept my answer if your problem is fixed.